# How to use boost::object_pool<>::construct with a non const reference as a ctor parameter?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-management, pool

Is it somehow possible to use boost::object_pool<>::construct with non const references?

The following snippet doesn't compile (VS2010):

```
foo::foo(bar & b)
{
}

static boost::shared_ptr<foo> foo::create(bar & b)
{
  return boost::shared_ptr<foo>(foo_pool.construct(b),
    boost::bind(& boost::object_pool<foo>::destroy, & foo_pool, _1));
}
```

VS2010 complains about not being able to convert bar & to const bar &. Looking at boost::object_pool<>::construct the reason ist clear:

```
element_type * construct(const T0 & a0)
```

I can't make the ctor parameter const though. Is there a trick to make boost::object_pool<> work with my foo class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`boost::ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/ref.html):

```
static boost::shared_ptr<foo> foo::create(bar & b)
{
  return boost::shared_ptr<foo>(foo_pool.construct(boost::ref(b)),
    boost::bind(& boost::object_pool<foo>::destroy, & foo_pool, _1));
}
```

`boost::ref` makes a `reference_wrapper`. Because that uses a pointer, it can be copied around however you wish, and implicitly dereferenced into a reference to the original value.